# RxJS with redux - emitting action when finished (with mergeMap)

Tags: javascript, redux, rxjs, reactive-programming

This is my current epic that I've written:

```
const storiesURL = 'https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty';
const topStoryURL = id => `https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/${id}.json?print=pretty`;
const maxAtOnce = 15;

const fetchStoriesEpic = action$ => action$.pipe(
  ofType(actions.FETCH_STORIES),
  debounceTime(100),
  switchMap(() => ajax.getJSON(storiesURL)), // 1. After that I have an array of ids
  map(ids => ids.slice(0, maxAtOnce).map(topStoryURL)), // 2. After that I have an array of 15 of the latest ids
  mergeMap(urls => from(urls)), // 3. After that I have those URLs
  mergeMap(url => ajax.getJSON(url), null, 3), // 4. After that I have those responses
  scan((acc, val) => [...acc, val] , []), // 5. Here I accumulate the responses into an array of stories
  map(stories => actions.fetchStoriesFullfilled(stories)), // 6. Here I dispatch an action, so it passes those stories once at a time as they arrive
  // ignoreElements(),
);
```

At `FETCH_STORIES` I make my `loading` attribute inside of state to `true`. I would like to set it to false as those requests finish, but not after single one of them, but when they finish all (in this case 15 requests).

**How can I achieve this?**

BTW - is this a common pattern? Do you know any resources where I can find RxJS patterns for async actions (that I will actually use)?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simplify your stream. For example:

```js
const { of, forkJoin, concat } = rxjs;
const { switchMap, map } = rxjs.operators;
const { ajax } = rxjs.ajax;

/**
 * test action creators
 */
const actions = {
  fetchStoriesStartLoading: () => ({type: 'fetchStoriesStartLoading'}),
  fetchStoriesDoneLoading: () => ({type: 'fetchStoriesDoneLoading'}),
  fetchStoriesFulfilled: (stories) => ({type: 'fetchStoriesFulfilled', stories}),
};

/**
 * configuration
 */
const storiesURL = 'https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty';
const topStoryURL = id => `https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/${id}.json?print=pretty`;
const maxAtOnce = 15;

/**
 * this stream loads configured number of stories
 */
const stories$ = ajax.getJSON(storiesURL).pipe(
  // switch to loading individual requests, forkJoin will wait until all are resolved
  switchMap(ids => forkJoin(
    // use only max number of ids
    ids.slice(0, maxAtOnce)
      // and map those to requests
      .map(id => ajax.getJSON(topStoryURL(id))))),
);

/**
 * this stream wraps the stories$ stream with loading/fulfilled indicators
 */
const storiesWithLoadingIndicator$ = concat(
  // signal start loading
  of(actions.fetchStoriesStartLoading()),

  // load stories
  stories$.pipe(
    // signal fulfilled
    map(actions.fetchStoriesFulfilled)
  ),

  // signal done loading
  of(actions.fetchStoriesDoneLoading()),
);

/**
 * test
 */
storiesWithLoadingIndicator$.subscribe(console.log);

/**
 * as an epic
 */
const fetchStoriesEpic = action$ => action$.pipe(
  ofType(actions.FETCH_STORIES),
  debounceTime(100),
  switchMapTo(storiesWithLoadingIndicator$)
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.2.1/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but I think the following should work:

```
const fetchStoriesEpic = action$ => action$.pipe(
  ofType(actions.FETCH_STORIES),
  debounceTime(100),
  switchMap(() => ajax.getJSON(storiesURL)),
  map(ids => ids.slice(0, maxAtOnce).map(topStoryURL)),
  mergeMap(urls => from(urls)),
  mergeMap(url => ajax.getJSON(url), null, 3).pipe(
    // instead of scan use reduce to wait for completion
    reduce((acc, val) => [...acc, val] , []),
  )
  // once they're all done, then return
  map(stories => actions.fetchStoriesFullfilled(stories)),
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I think this can be done even easier with `mergeMap` with `forkJoin`, but this way I get only the result after the last request has finished :(